# Store High score Securely

Tags: python

I am curtly programming a High score game and I want to store the High score in a way that it can't be modified even if you have the Source Code. Is there any way to do that? Maybe using a Signature?

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple database liek a text file or json.
The highscore can’t even be stored in the source code what are you talking about?
Please be more clear on what you want. Do you want to store it locally or on the cloud?

Comment: I want to store it localy in like a text file. If I store it in a JSON file the User could modify it.

Comment: @David Glänzel If you store it in a txt the user would be able to modify it. Maybe if you encrypt the data it would be more difficult to modify it without crashing the game

Comment: I had the same idea but as far as I know I would have to store the Password in the Code ore a file then the user could use the password to modify the Score(my friends have to much time). Is there any way that I don't have to store the Password?